# Django filter many to many relationship with count

Tags: django, orm

Lets consider the following scenario - books can be shared by multiple students.

```
class Student(models.Model):
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='students')
```

I would like to find, for a given student, all the books shared/owned only by this student. I did the following:

```
s = Student.objects.get(id=1)
s.books.annotate(student_count=Count('students').filter(student_count=1)
```

However, it returns all the books of student `s` (equivalent to `s.books.all()`). Later, I got the desired result with following query:

```
Book.objects.annotate(student_count=Count('students')).\
filter(students=s, student_count=1)
```

Why do I not get the expected result with the first query?

Comment: Your last snippet is completely invalid. Would cause `Invalid Syntax` exception

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov I have added the missing bracket. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This queryset

```
s.books.annotate(student_count=Count('students').filter(student_count=1)
```

generates the same SQL query as

```
Book.objects.filter(students=s).annotate(student_count=Count('students')).filter(student_count=1)
```

and because [order of annotate() and filter() matters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses), you do not get the expected result (every book will have `student_count` equal to 1).

Comment: Is there any reason (rational of design choice) whey that query translates to the one you said instead of `Book.objects.annotate(student_count=Count('students')).\
filter(students=s, student_count=1)` which looks more natural to me.

Comment: @DurgaDatta I guess `s.books` translates to `Book.objects.filter(student=s)`, which is natural, and other methods of `s.books` are just appended to `Book.objects.filter(student=s)`.

Comment: @Vladmir Since even in the query you wrote , annotation comes after filter so it should correctly annotate those filtered books, right?

Comment: @DurgaDatta Quoting Django docs: "If in doubt, inspect the SQL query!" You can print `query` property of those querysets: `print(qs.query)`.